# Get only the collaborators, not the owners of the ORG of the github repo

Tags: git, github, postman, github-api, github-api-v3

I have Github Organization with the owners Owner1 and Owner2 and members Member1 and Member2.
Now I created a new repository in this Organization and added two users as collaborators (user1 and user2) of this repo.

Now the result of `postman` with the below GET request will result in the following:

```
Owner1
Owner2
user1
user2
```

POSTMAN request : `https://<github-host>/api/v3/repos/<my-gihub-org>/<my-github-repo>/collaborators?per_page=100`

But I am interested in listing only the collaborators i.e., **user1** and **user2**; Not the **owners**.

Could someone please help me here..!

Comment: hi how is it possible to have two owners for a repository ? and an owner is a colloborator by default

Comment: Owners are for the complete organization; I have added two members as the owner role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `affiliation` parameter, in order to filter out any collaborators that directly work on a certain project.

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: <bearer KEY>" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
     -XGET https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/collaborators\?affiliation\=direct
```

This should return just the people who work on a project, and not **both** collaborators and owners.

GitHub states that:

> affiliation | string | query
> Filter collaborators returned by their affiliation. Can be one of:
>
> - outside: All outside collaborators of an organization-owned repository.
> - direct: All collaborators with permissions to an organization-owned repository, regardless of organization membership status.
> - all: All collaborators the authenticated user can see.

**If** it so happens that an *owner* is also a direct collaborator to this repo, then you have to do another request, where you check which person is the owner, and then filter them out from the collaborators request.

---

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: <bearer KEY>" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
     -XGET https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/members\?role\=admin
```

With this request, you can check which are the owners of an organization.

---

If you fancy using the new graphql feature, then you can query for

```
{
  organization(login: "org_name") {
    id
    name
    repository(name: "repo_name") {
      collaborators(affiliation: DIRECT, first: N) {
        edges {
          permission
          node {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A owner is a collaborator by default so it will always return the owner , you can check  for users with admin flag off if that is what you meant by owner

I am not sure how a repository could have two owners

Use the latest git api:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators
```

you can use below pre-requesst script in postman to print only non owners:

```
const postRequest = {
    url: ' https://api.github.com/orgs/<org>/members\role=admin',
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
    },
    auth: {
        "type": "basic",
        "basic": [
            { "key": "username", "value": "<yourusername>" },
            { "key": "password", "value": "<yourtoken>" }
        ]
    }

};
pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, responseOwner) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("THe errror is : " + JSON.stringify(error))
    } else {
        for (let i of pm.response.json()) {
            let found = 0;
            for (let j of responseOwner.json()) {
                i.login === j.login ? found = 1 : null
            }
            found === 1 ? null : console.log(i)
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Owners are for the complete organization; I have added two members as the owner role.
I know that the owners are the default collaborators for any repo created under that organization. But I am interested in fetching only those collaborators who are added via  here: `https://<github-host>/<org>/<repo>/settings/access`

Comment: /orgs/{org}/members?role=admin gives admins may be you can filter the users which are not common in both ?

Comment: Added a prerequist script that will help you to filter out  using the members url